# Sort ascending doesn't run in function

Tags: javascript

Here is my demo: [js fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wssbqrv2/1/)

```
function sortByPrice() {
    tableOfCars.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.price - b.price;
    });
}
```

i dont know why my function sortByPrice() doesn't work. When i delete sortByPrice function and leave only code inside, it works and shows prices ascending onload automatically.

Comment: Are you calling `sortByPrice` anywhere?

Comment: `tableOfCars` is an array; sorting it after the table is generated will have absolutely no effect on the table, which you need to rebuild after the sort is complete.

Comment: i call sortByPrice by clicking button. so how to fix it?

Comment: after return i am calling function showTable()   then button works, but table appearing twice ;/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function sortByPrice() {
    // sort the cars
    tableOfCars.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.price - b.price;
    });
    // empty the table
    var tbody = document.getElementById("tabcars").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
    while (tbody.firstChild) {
        tbody.removeChild(t.firstChild);
    }
    // rebuild the table
    showTable();
}
```

Comment: works great, thanks:)  but i don't understand while loop

Comment: The while loop says while the table body node's firstChild node is not null remove the first child from the DOM. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_firstchild.asp http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_removechild.asp